# Restricting access to user submitted code in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I'm working on a rails application that takes ruby code as input and executes it. Since the code submitted comes from an untrusted domain, I want to restrict access to certain methods and modules. For example, I don't want users to access `File.read` or `open()`.

Also, is it possible to restrict access to only a few modules? Only modules from a whitelist can be required from user submitted code.

I can probably do a validation on the user code, but I wanted to check if ruby language or any modules already have this capability.

Codeschool.com has interactive tutorials. I am wondering if they restrict access to user code or do any validation at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always used [shikashi](https://github.com/tario/shikashi) with satisfaction for this kind of tasks.

Comment: This looked very promising, but the version (0.5.2) I used was very buggy. Some of the examples did not work [link](https://github.com/tario/shikashi/blob/master/examples/basic/example2.rb).

Answer (score 3):

Ruby has a built in feature for that, `$SAFE`

Some basic intro you can find here http://edwinmeyer.com/Release_Integrated_RHG_09_10_2008/chapter07.html
and then you can easily google more (I can recommend only books)

Also take a look in here
http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/taint.html

From what I remember the solution here is to load your app, then raise `$SAFE` level to 4 in a thread, execute code there (this can't be lowered later so you first need to allow Rails to load in level 0)