# Restrictions on user-submitted code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Ruby on Rails application, and one of its functions is to present JSON data to the user in table form. Before this step, I intend to add a way for users to tweak the JSON data by means of uploading their own Ruby code files that handle this.

This has its dangers. I definitely don't want any form of access (reading or writing) to the databases, nor do I want it to be able to call anything in another file. How can I limit the file in this way?

Essentially all I need is for the main code to call the function in the user-submitted file with the JSON as the parameter, and returning JSON back. All logic during this manipulation of the JSON must happen in and only in the user file.

---

I've looked around for ways to do this with no luck. I've seen this question:

[Restricting access to user submitted code in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906954/restricting-access-to-user-submitted-code-in-rails)

The issue here is that I'd prefer an approach that doesn't require a gem. Also sandboxing seems rather complicated for the approach I want, which is a blanket restriction, and not specific things.

I intend to raise the $SAFE level to 4 before calling the user-supplied code/method. That doesn't seem to prevent calling other methods in the application though.

Comment: Does it have to be ruby? It can be JS or lua, for example. This way you naturally don't have to `eval` user input.

Comment: I'm open to JS too if it helps with this restriction issue.

Comment: The answer seems to be "just use JRuby" :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169303/how-to-run-untrusted-ruby-code-inside-a-safe-sandbox

Comment: Do a search for ruby sandboxes: https://github.com/tario/shikashi

Comment: I looked at Shikashi, but from what I've read it's riddled with bugs.